# Dynamically changing picture causes chromium error

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, webkit

I'm using jQuery+jQuery Mobile+Cordova for a mobile phone app and need to dynamically change a picture. Of course this isn't a challenge and I simply use

```
$('myElement').attr('src', 'img/myImage' + someIndex + '.png');
```

But whenever this gets executed, I get an `Unknown Chromium Error: -6` in my LogCat. The image(s) are still being displayed just fine, but I'm wondering where this is coming from? Commenting this line out makes the error go away, so it has to be this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just happened to realize what the problem was. I was displaying, say, `n` images, but I only showed `k < n` of them (i.e. 3 of 5 total). The ones not being displayed accidentally were set to have a non-existing image, causing the error. Since they weren't being displayed, there was no visible problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `Unknown Chromium Error: -6` error most probably occurs due to a malformed URL.

You can try changing your code to:

```
$('#myElement').attr('src', 'file:///android_asset/img/myImage' + someIndex + '.png');
```

The prefix `file:///android_asset/` can be used to load content from the current application's assets folder.

Comment: I tried that too, but it gives the same error. In both cases the images still work, though.

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue. But couldn't trace a solution on either of the given answers.

For me, I needed to replace the html each time I needed to replace the image. Roughly speaking my code looked like this:

```
function updateImage(src) {
    $('#src_parent_div').html("<img src='" + src + "' />");
}
```